# Angular.js $cookies : not properly saved/loaded

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I am trying to use a simple input that can be retrieved by a cookie automatically.

My angular controller is :

```
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('mantis', ['ngCookies']);
    app.controller('main', function($scope, $cookies) {

        $scope.nom = '';

        $scope.WriteNom = function () {
            $cookies.put('Nom', $scope.nom);
        };

        $scope.ReadNom = function () {
            $scope.nom = $cookies.get('Nom');
            return $scope.nom;
        };

    });
</script>
```

In my page, I made a div where I can change the variable "nom" flawlessly.
The value should be loaded with ng-init (from cookie)
It changes with ng-model
And it should be saved with ng-click

```
<div class="container" ng-app="mantis" ng-controller="main">

    <!-- Assigné à -->
    <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="input-group" ng-init="nom=ReadNom()">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" placeholder="Assigné à (id)" ng-model="nom">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" ng-click="WriteNom()">Sauvegarder</button>
                </span>
            </div>
    </div>
    (...)
```

And then, somewhere else, i can use "nom" where I need it by using {{nom}}

It's almost working :

- The value is properly changed when I type in the input box and I can use it
- The cookie is not changed when I click on the button nor it's loaded when I load the page

Comment: is your controller separated or on same file?

Comment: It's on the same file. And finally I made a mistake somewhere else. Now, it look like there is just the Cookie who is not saved. The error did not came from here (I am editing my question)

Comment: I changed my question. There is no error but no cookie either :)

Comment: what is the angular version?

Comment: angular and angular-cookies are both 1.4.8

Comment: Maybe ng-init="nom=ReadNom()" is creating another variable that is not $scope.nom ? I don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the return part,

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="input-group" ng-init="ReadNom()">
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.ReadNom = function () {
   $scope.nom = $cookies.get('Nom');          
 };
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/x3Hf8reRRh2BZo8XCczl?p=preview)**

Comment: I changes absolutely nothing =)

Comment: @RonanLamour no it does, check the change and demo

Comment: did you change the ng-init part?

Comment: Yes, I changed both. But my page contains more  than my example. I am trying to edit your plunker and get it working

Comment: In fact, when I inspect my page with chrome, I can't find any cookie when I click on "Sauvegarder"

Comment: do you have team viewer?

Comment: Yes but I am at work and can't give access (security blabla) but really, thank you to try to provide help like that. Look like when I add my page to plank, the problem is back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129464/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-ronan-lamour).

Comment: plunker link please